# turf.nearestPointOnLine() returns different distance when several nodes are passed at once

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, turf

For my question I have prepared [a jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/n91srj38/) where you can drag a marker around and the nearest way is drawn in red color:

[image: animated OSM map]

```js
function distancePointSegment(lat, lng, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
  var pt = turf.point([lng, lat]);
  var line = turf.lineString([
    [lng1, lat1],
    [lng2, lat2]
  ]);
  var snapped = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, pt);
  
  return snapped.properties.dist;
}

function distancePointSegmentBroken(lat, lng, list) {
  var pt = turf.point([lng, lat]);
  var line = turf.lineString(list);
  var snapped = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, pt);
  
  return snapped.properties.dist;
}

function findNearestWayId(ways, nodes) {
  var markerPosition = draggableMarker.getLatLng();
  var shortestDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  var nearestWayId;
  for (var wayId in ways) {
    var prevNodeLat = Number.NaN;
    var prevNodeLng = Number.NaN;

    var way = ways[wayId];
    // iterate all nodes of a way object and save their positions
    // as a list of Leaflet latLng objects in the way object
    way.latLngs = [];
    // also save the minimal distance from the way object to the marker position
    way.minDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    for (var n in way.nodes) {
      var nodeId = way.nodes[n];
      var node = nodes[nodeId];
      way.latLngs.push(node.latLng);

      // find the minimal distance among the segments of the way
      if (!isNaN(prevNodeLat) && !isNaN(prevNodeLng)) {
        var distance = distancePointSegment(
            markerPosition.lat, 
          markerPosition.lng, 
          prevNodeLat, 
          prevNodeLng, 
          node.latLng.lat, 
          node.latLng.lng
        );
        if (distance < way.minDistance) {
          way.minDistance = distance;
        }
      }

      prevNodeLat = node.latLng.lat;
      prevNodeLng = node.latLng.lng;
    }
    
    var brokenDistance = distancePointSegmentBroken(
      markerPosition.lat, 
      markerPosition.lng, 
      way.latLngs.map(pos => [pos.lat, pos.lng])
    );

    console.log('For way ' + wayId + ' distancePointSegment result in km: ' + way.minDistance);
    console.log('For way ' + wayId + ' distancePointSegmentBroken result in km: ' + brokenDistance);

    // find the overall shortest distance among all ways
    if (way.minDistance < shortestDistance) {
      shortestDistance = way.minDistance;
      nearestWayId = wayId;
    }
  }

  return nearestWayId;
}

// draw ways as polylines with popups
function drawPolylines(ways, nearestWayId) {
  var markerPosition = draggableMarker.getLatLng();
  for (var wayId in ways) {
    var way = ways[wayId];
    var line = L.polyline(way.latLngs, { color: (wayId === nearestWayId ? 'red' : 'blue') });

    var markerLatStr = parseFloat(markerPosition.lat).toFixed(6);
    var markerLngStr = parseFloat(markerPosition.lng).toFixed(6);
    var minDistanceStr = parseFloat(1000 * way.minDistance).toFixed(2);

    var popupMsg = '<p>Way: <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/' + wayId + '" target="_blank">' + wayId + '</a></p>' + 
        '<p>Distance to the car at<br>' + markerLatStr + ',' + markerLngStr + ':</p><p>' + minDistanceStr + ' meter</p>';
    line.bindPopup(popupMsg);

    line.addTo(lineGroup);
  }
}

function processOverpassReply(data) {
  var ways = { };
  var nodes = { };

  console.log('Received Overpass API reply with ' + data.elements.length + ' elements');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.elements.length; i++) {
    var element = data.elements[i];
    var type = element.type;

    if (type === 'way') {
      var wayId = element.id;
      ways[wayId] = element;
    } 
    else if (type === 'node') {
      var nodeId = element.id;
      var nodeLat = element.lat;
      var nodeLng = element.lon;
      nodes[nodeId] = element;
      element.latLng = L.latLng(nodeLat, nodeLng);
    }
  }

  var nearestWayId = findNearestWayId(ways, nodes);
  var minDistanceStr = parseFloat(1000 * ways[nearestWayId].minDistance).toFixed(2);
  console.log('The nearest way id: ' + nearestWayId + ' with the shortest distance of ' + minDistanceStr + ' meter will be drawn in red color');
  //console.log(ways);
  //console.log(nodes);
  drawPolylines(ways, nearestWayId);
}

function sendOverpassRequest() {
  var markerPosition = draggableMarker.getLatLng();
  // return ways and nodes with non-empty "highway" tag around the draggable marker position
  var query = 'way(around:20,' + markerPosition.lat + ',' + markerPosition.lng + ')[highway~"."];(._;>;);out;';
  console.log('Sending Overpass API query: ' + query);

  if (overpassLayer != null) {
    // remove all lines
    lineGroup.clearLayers();

    map.removeLayer(overpassLayer);
    overpassLayer = null;
  }

  overpassLayer = new L.OverPassLayer({
    minZoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 18,
    endPoint: 'https://overpass-api.de/api/',
    query: query,
    onSuccess: processOverpassReply
  });

  map.addLayer(overpassLayer);
}

function sendOverpassRequest() {
  var position = draggableMarker.getLatLng();
  // return ways and nodes with non-empty "highway" tag around the draggable marker position
  var query = 'way(around:' + 50 + ',' + position.lat + ',' + position.lng + ')[highway~"."];(._;>;);out;';
  console.log('Sending Overpass API query: ' + query);

  if (overpassLayer != null) {
    // remove all lines
    lineGroup.clearLayers();

    map.removeLayer(overpassLayer);
    overpassLayer = null;
  }

  overpassLayer = new L.OverPassLayer({
    minZoom: 9,
    maxZoom: 18,
    endPoint: 'https://overpass-api.de/api/',
    query: query,
    onSuccess: processOverpassReply
  });
  map.addLayer(overpassLayer);
}

var startPosition = [51.4661, 7.2491];
var zoomOptions = {
  minZoom: 9,
  maxZoom: 18
};

var map = L.map('map', zoomOptions).setView(startPosition, 16);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var draggableMarker = L.marker(startPosition, {
  draggable: true
})
.addTo(map)
.on('dragend', sendOverpassRequest);

var lineGroup = L.layerGroup();
map.addLayer(lineGroup);

var overpassLayer;

sendOverpassRequest();
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#map {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-overpass-layer@2/src/OverPassLayer.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-overpass-layer@2/dist/OverPassLayer.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

The above demo works well, when I pass only 2 nodes to the function below and keep track of the minimal distance from the draggable marker to the way (i.e. the function below is called *multiple* times):

```
function distancePointSegment(lat, lng, lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
  var pt = turf.point([lng, lat]);
  var line = turf.lineString([
    [lng1, lat1],
    [lng2, lat2]
  ]);
  var snapped = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, pt);
  
  return snapped.properties.dist;
}
```

However when I pass all nodes of a way object to the function below at once  (i.e. the function below is called a *single* time), then the returned distance is way too high:

```
function distancePointSegmentBroken(lat, lng, list) {
  var pt = turf.point([lng, lat]);
  var line = turf.lineString(list);
  var snapped = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, pt);
  
  return snapped.properties.dist;
}
```

I have marked the mismatching distance values with a red rectangle in the animated picture above.

What is happening here?

The documentation for [turf.nearestPointOnLine](https://turfjs.org/docs/#nearestPointOnLine) shows passing multiple locations in its example and I am just trying to do the same:

```
var line = turf.lineString([
    [-77.031669, 38.878605],
    [-77.029609, 38.881946],
    [-77.020339, 38.884084],
    [-77.025661, 38.885821],
    [-77.021884, 38.889563],
    [-77.019824, 38.892368]
]);
var pt = turf.point([-77.037076, 38.884017]);

var snapped = turf.nearestPointOnLine(line, pt, {units: 'miles'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library expects coordinates to be in `[lng, lat]` order (see for example https://turfjs.org/docs/#point), but when preparing line string coordinates for `distancePointSegmentBroken` function your points have coordinates in `[lat, lng]` order. You could find this out yourselves from usage of turf.js functions in `distancePointSegment` function.

So all you have to do is change order of points coordinates:

```
var brokenDistance = distancePointSegmentBroken(
  markerPosition.lat, 
  markerPosition.lng, 
  way.latLngs.map(pos => [pos.lng, pos.lat])
);
```